# Basic automation python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to set up a simple macro in a game, but he has to press the keys until he sees "test.png". If he sees it, he should make a certain key combination and keep pressing the keys again, but he keeps pressing the keys without seeing "test.png".

```
import pyautogui
import time
play = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("test.png")


while True:

  if play:
      pyautogui.click(x=1182, y=919)
      time.sleep(5)
  else:
      pyautogui.click(x=1512,y=929)
  
  if play:
      pyautogui.click(x=1182, y=919)
      time.sleep(5)
  else:
       pyautogui.click(x=865,y=488)
  if play:
      pyautogui.click(x=1182, y=919)
      time.sleep(5)
  else:
      pyautogui.click(x=909,y=753)
  if play:
      pyautogui.click(x=1182, y=919)
      time.sleep(5)
  else:
      pyautogui.click(x=1647,y=933)
  if play:
      pyautogui.click(x=1182, y=919)
      time.sleep(5)
  else:
      pyautogui.click(x=1781,y=946)
  if play:
       pyautogui.click(x=1182, y=919)
       time.sleep(5)
  else:
      pyautogui.click(x=1289,y=511)
  if play:
      pyautogui.click(x=1182, y=919)
      time.sleep(5)
  else:
      pyautogui.click(x=695,y=546)
```

Comment: (1) The indentation and syntax of the code is incorrect. (2) The repetition of code is unnecessary, that's what loops are for. (3) You only call `locateOnScreen` once and set `play`. You must do this repeatedly to update `play`. (4) You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.